# Spider program Python AttributeError: Object has no attribute

Tags: python, web-crawler, pyspider

I just start learning Python. And I want to write a Spider program to get some jokes on web.
When I run the program it warning :'AttributeError: 'Spider_Model' object has no attribute 'pages'.
And the solutions I've found online do not work.Here is the code.Please have a look.

```
import urllib.request as  request
import re
#import _thread
import time

class Spider_Model:

def __int__(self):
    self.page = 1
    self.pages = []
    self.enable = False

# Download all the jokes and save it to the list
def GetPage(self, page):
    myUrl = 'https://www.qiushibaike.com/hot/' + str(page)
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) \
                  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
    headers = {'User_Agent' : user_agent}
    req = request.Request(myUrl, headers = headers)
    myResponse = request.urlopen(req)
    myPage = myResponse.read()

    # The role of decode is to convert other encoded strings into unicode string
    unicodePage = myPage.decode('utf-8')
    myItems = re.findall('<span>(.*?)</span>', unicodePage, re.s)
    items = []
    for item in myItems:
        items.append(item[0].repalce("\n", ""), item[1].replace("\n", ""))
    return items

# Download new jokes
def LoadPage(self):
    # If users doesn't enter quit, keep download
    while self.enable:
        # If the pages array less than 2
        if len(self.pages) < 2:
            try:
                 myPage = self.GetPage(str(self.page))
                 self.page += 1
                 self.pages.append(myPage)
            except:
                 print('Connection failed')
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

def ShowPage(self, nowPage, page):
    for items in nowPage:
        print('No.%d Page:'% page, items[0], items[1])
        myInput = input()
        if myInput == 'quit':
            self.enable = False
            break

def Start(self):
    self.enable = True
    page = 0
    print('Loading...')
    # _thread.start_new_thread(self.LoadPage(), ())
    while self.enable:
        if len(self.pages) > 0:
            nowPage = self.pages[0]
            page += 1
            del self.pages[0]
            self.ShowPage(nowPage, page)


print('Hit Enter:')
input(' ')
myModel = Spider_Model()
myModel.Start()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlIbJ.png)

Comment: `__int__` -> `__init__`

Comment: That code is not indented correctly; proper indentation is _vital_ in Python. It looks like your `__int__` method should actually be  named `__init__`.

Comment: OH ,What a stupid mistake. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thanks ,I have solved my problem.